# Unable to create a Class in a Folder in VS 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on a tutorial and I am asked to create a Class in a Folder by doing right-click on the "Models" folder but the option of creating a Class is not available. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I have tried adding a new Class from the File>>New>>File and then I saved directly in the PC's Folder where I am supposed to save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click on the Folder-> Add -> new item -> A dialog will popup and Class should be in the list of items that you can create

Answer (score 1):

instead of right-clicking to create a new class, try right-clicking on your new folder and choosing "Add", then "New Item".  You can then create your class from this window.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks man, but unfortunately I am not able to do so... I have tried a few other options but I have not managed so far